# Create a new table from an existing table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make this query to accept dynamic table names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966428/how-can-i-make-this-query-to-accept-dynamic-table-names)

I would like to create a new table from an exiting table using stored procedure. I am new in this but no problem learning. Anyway this is what I have done:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CreateNewTable

    @NewTable nvarchar(1000),
    @OldTable nvarchar(1000)
    AS
    SELECT *
    INTO @NewTable
    FROM @OldTable
    WHERE 1 = 2                
GO
```

It gives me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@NewTable'

Please dig in and help...

Comment: This is dynamic SQL.  Read about it.  There are about 12,000 questions on this on SO already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dynamic SQL, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CreateNewTable
    @NewTable nvarchar(1000),
    @OldTable nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @NewTable + ' FROM ' + @OldTable + ' WHERE 1=1'

EXEC sp_executesql @query

END
```

Comment: thank you Fosco I do appreciate your help... Learning this is cool....take care man....

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable names directly for the names of objects. You'd have to compose a string representing your SELECT statement and execute it as dynamic SQL.

Comment: Please vote to close instead of answering, Joe!  We have so many Dynamic SQL questions already.