# SQL Server : How to fetch data from dynamic multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

Using SQL SERVER.

The database contains data from different years, somehow I want to fetch all the data (all the years) and show to the user, for example, database contains table:

```
table
--------
records_2000_01
records_2000_02
records_2000_03
...
```

now through 
select TABLE_NAME into @tableName from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'records_%'

I can fetch all the table name, how to write a SQL (or perhaps procedure) to fetch all data from these tables? make all record into one table?

thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make this query to accept dynamic table names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966428/how-can-i-make-this-query-to-accept-dynamic-table-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create procedure in this Below steps you need to follow.

- `Create table Common_Table` with same one structure which all your table like records_2000_02 and others.
- Use loop or cursor for all records you get from  information_schema which match your table name
- Create dynamic sql like `' Insert into your Common_Table select * from ' + Table_name` that you get from Information_schema.

  - Then you get all your data in one table Common_Table

Comment: yep, i already get it working, but I can;t post the answer yet, since my "reputation is too low", I cannot answer my own question.... what the heck is this :P

Comment: You can need to visit site regular and contribution to the community so you get more reputation and you can do that thing in future.